# How to create a square image with Pillow?

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I have a Django project which allows images to be uploaded. Currently, the uploaded images are only being resized and compressed. Also, because I am using an S3 server for static files the images are first saved in a memfile and then in the server.

The problem is that the current setup only works in production when using the S3 server. When running the app locally, the images do not get resized or compressed.

I would also like to remove the current resize method and instead fill the image to be a square. For example, if the height is larger than the width, fill the image width with white padding to create a square and resize it to 500x500. Any transparent areas on the image should also be filled with a white background.

If anyone can help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

**models.py**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.product.save()
    return instance

    if self.image:
        memfile = BytesIO()
        img = Image.open(self.image)
        if img.mode != 'RGBA':
            img = img.convert('RGBA')
        if img.width > 700:
            ratio = img.width / img.height
            height = 700 / ratio
            output_size = (700, height)
            img.thumbnail(output_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img)
        img.save(memfile, optimize=True, quality=90, format='PNG')
        default_storage.save(self.image.name, memfile)
        memfile.close()
        img.close()
```

Comment: What is the reason why resizing doesn't work locally? Does it throw any exception? What do you see in place of saved file locally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform a "vertical" image into a "horizontal" image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319690/how-to-transform-a-vertical-image-into-a-horizontal-image) For your use case, simply decide before-hand which dimension is larger, and apply the shown processing.

Comment: @Arty I only see the original uploaded file. No compression or resizing has been done.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMerwe That is because your code saves image to memory file only. You have to write it to file system. Instead of line `img.save(memfile, optimize=True, quality=90, format='PNG')` do line `img.save('/path/to/filename.png', optimize=True, quality=90, format='PNG')`, where `/path/to/filename.png` is your desired path and filename for storing resized image.

Comment: @Arty Is it possible to call the save method twice (for the memory file and the file system)?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMerwe Yes, it should be possible, you can do one and then another, in any order.